# What Scala feature allows the plus operator to be used on Any?

Tags: scala

I'm still learning Scala, and when I ran across an example in the Koans, I wasn't able to understand why it works:

```
var foo : Any = "foo"
println(foo + "bar")
```

Any doesn't have a + method

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is an implicit conversion in the [`scala.Predef`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Predef$) object:

```
implicit def any2stringadd(x: Any): StringAdd
```

[StringAdd](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/master/src/library/scala/runtime/StringAdd.scala) defines a `+` operator/method:

```
def +(other: String) = String.valueOf(self) + other
```

Also, since scala.Predef is always in scope, that implicit conversion will always work.

Comment: `StringAdd` lives in `scala.runtime` ([source code on Github](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/master/src/library/scala/runtime/StringAdd.scala)). I'm not sure why it doesn't show up in [ScalaDoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.runtime.package).

Comment: Thanks for the link- I've added it into my answer

Comment: @Kipton Interresting "not in scaladoc", are there any other traits/objects not in scaladoc? (One assumes to find every scala trait/object in scaladoc) Seems to me worth a new SO question...

Comment: There is some ignore list ... you could probably have a look if the class is mentioned there.

Comment: You can see the code that is generated by applying implicit conversions with the `-Xprint:typer` option. The output is a bit verbose, but by running `scala -Xprint:typer` you can see that the command in question is converted to `scala.this.Predef.println(scala.this.Predef.any2stringadd($anon.this.foo).+("bar"))`.

Answer (score 1):

It works because of implicit conversions which *"fixes"* certain type errors for which conversions have been provided. Here is more info on the mechanism of implicit conversions:

http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/implicit-conversions-and-parameters.html#21.2

In fact it uses this very same example `x + y` to explain how it works. This is from the 1st edition of the book, but the explanation is still valid.