# Polymorphic Methods in Scala- why is this allowed?

Tags: scala, types, polymorphism, type-inference

I have the following polymorphic method in scala:

```
  def addTwoThings[S](item1:S, item2:S) =
  {
    item1 + " | " + item2
  }
```

The following however compiles fine, even though I've specified that item1 and item2 should be the same type "S". Do I need to do something with implicit evidence ?

To be clear, I actually want the compiler to complain that they're not the same type, but it seems to be allowing me to proceed, which is what's confusing me. Thanks.

```
println(addTwoThings("1",2))
```

Comment: the answer lies in `Predef` - there is special implicits for `String`

Comment: Thanks dk14. Can you elaborate a bit more on this ? Is there anyway I can enforce type safety for clients of my method ?

Comment: I'll try to add a solution in the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you get `+` operator is working for you without using `.toString` explicitly is described here: [What Scala feature allows the plus operator to be used on Any?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465753/what-scala-feature-allows-the-plus-operator-to-be-used-on-any). Those additional implicits in `Predef` are source of many problems in scala, but it's hard to get rid of such legacy.

To find out why `addTwoThings("1",2)` is working - let's rewrite it to get exact inference for `S`:

```
scala> def addTwoThings[S](item1:S, item2:S): S = item1
addTwoThings: [S](item1: S, item2: S)S

scala> addTwoThings(1, "1")
res5: Any = 1
```

You can notice that type `S = Any` was inferred as a common type.

So, here are several solutions:

1) If you can allow two type-parameters in your method's signature, here is the solution:

```
def addTwoThings[S1, S2](item1:S1, item2:S2)(implicit ev: S1 =:= S2, ev2: S2 =:= S1) = {
    item1 + " | " + item2
}
```

Note: ev2 might be redundant for check, but it provides more complete equality, see [Scala: generic method using implicit evidence doesn't compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30699996/scala-generic-method-using-implicit-evidence-doesnt-compile)

Experiments:

```
scala> addTwoThings(1, "1")
<console>:18: error: Cannot prove that Int =:= String.
              addTwoThings(1, "1")
                          ^

scala> addTwoThings("2", "1")
res11: String = 2 | 1
```

---

2) Or you can exclude `Any`/`AnyRef` (common supertype for everything) using [Evidence that types are not equal in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24519487/evidence-that-types-are-not-equal-in-scala) :

```
trait =:!=[A, B]
implicit def neq[A, B] : A =:!= B = new =:!=[A, B] {}
implicit def neqAmbig1[A] : A =:!= A = ???
implicit def neqAmbig2[A] : A =:!= A = ???

def addTwoThings[S](item1:S, item2:S)(implicit ev: S =:!= Any, ev2: S =:!= AnyRef): S = item1
```

Experiments:

```
scala> addTwoThings(1, "1")
<console>:18: error: ambiguous implicit values:
 both method neqAmbig1 of type [A]=> =:!=[A,A]
 and method neqAmbig2 of type [A]=> =:!=[A,A]
 match expected type =:!=[Any,Any]
              addTwoThings(1, "1")
                          ^

scala> addTwoThings(1, 1)
res7: Int = 1
```

Note: This approach doesn't require exact type equality, so if `B1 <: B2` - `addTwoThings(b1, b2)` - will still work. It protects you only from unrelated type hierarchies (which might be useful). In practice `!= Any` without `!= AnyRef` will not give you error on `object A; object B; addTwoThings(B, A)`.

Note2: The error provided by compiler is hardly readable, more info here - [How can I customize Scala ambiguous implicit errors when using shapeless type inequalities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25006443/how-can-i-customize-scala-ambiguous-implicit-errors-when-using-shapeless-type-in)

---

3) Another approach is currying:

```
def addTwoThings[S](item1:S)(item2:S) = ""
```

Experiments:

```
scala> addTwoThings(1)(1)
res8: String = ""

scala> addTwoThings(1)("1")
<console>:18: error: type mismatch;
 found   : String("1")
 required: Int
              addTwoThings(1)("1")
                              ^
```

Type inference will not look for common supertype of curried parameters (you can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27652463/1-listnothing-in-foldleft/27652729#27652729))

Comment: Thanks dk14! Is there anyway to make it explicitly require S be the exact same type as opposed to having a common super type ?

Comment: @NoviceHead88 yes, I've added two approaches to the answer: evidences and currying

Comment: @NoviceHead88 I explained 3 possible solutions. Whichever to pick depends on your exact requirements, as each of them has its own pros and cons

Comment: Awesome thx dk14! I think I'll be going with approach #2 :) as I might need to add more arguments and probably defining multiple type parameters .

Comment: (Continuation of above) Might start getting unwieldy especially since I just want to ensure all arguments are the exact same type.

Comment: I did notice you added a != AnyRef as well. Can you describe a case where just doing Any but not AnyRef might cause issues ? Thanks !

Comment: @NoviceHead88 the approach #2 doesn't require exact type equality, so if `B1 <: B2` - `addTwoThings(b1, b2)` - will still work. It protects you only from unrelated type hierarchies (which might be useful). In practice `!= Any` without `!= AnyRef` will not give you error on `object A; object B; addTwoThings(B, A)`

Comment: `Any` and `AnyRef` are the only types that can merge unrelated (independently created) type hierarchies

Answer (score 0):

Once again this is the problem of type inference of Scala Compiler

You have to give explicit type to guide the compiler

```
addTwoThings[String]("1",2)
```

The above will give compilation error.

**The reason why your code works**

The common super type of String and Int is Any. So the Scala compiler is assuming `S` in the function to `Any`

```
scala> def addTwoThings[S](item1:S, item2:S) =
     |   {
     |     item1 + " | " + item2
     |   }
addTwoThings: [S](item1: S, item2: S)String

scala> println(addTwoThings("1",2))
1 | 2

scala> println(addTwoThings[String]("1",2))
<console>:22: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(2)
 required: String
       println(addTwoThings[String]("1",2))
```

Comment: Thanks pamu ! In this case, aside from specifying the type expliclty when calling the method like you ahve done with addTwoThings[String], is there any other way to enforce this in definition of the method itself ?